# dimension problem using VGG16 architecture

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, reshape

I have tried to use the vgg16 architecture and afterward a convolution layer.
I know the output of vgg16 is suppose to be 512 channels of 7x7, but for some reason, it just gives the output as some sort of one-dimensional list.

therefore,I keep getting the following error : 
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 100 512 3 3, but got 2-dimensional input of size [64, 25088] instead

I've tried to reshape the output of the vgg16 with no success. any suggestions?
all I want is to put a convolution layer, and not fully connected layer, after the vgg16 so it won't have too many parameters

the code (only the part of vgg16 and the network I want to add )

```
#Choosing our pretrained network model
pre_trained_model = tv.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
pre_trained_model = pre_trained_model

# freeze parameters
for param in pre_trained_model.parameters():
param.requires_grad = False

# add layers to train
from collections import OrderedDict
#classifier = classifier.nn.Size([1, 512, 7, 7])
classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
                      ('conv1', nn.Conv2d(512, 100, 3)),
                      ('fc1', nn.Linear(2500, 400)),
                      ('dr1', nn.Dropout(p = 0.3)),
                      ('bn1', nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=400)),
                      ('relu2', nn.ReLU()),
                      ('fc2', nn.Linear(400, 100)),
                      ('dr2', nn.Dropout(p = 0.3)),
                      ('bn2', nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=100)),
                      ('relu3', nn.ReLU()),
                      ('fc3', nn.Linear(100, 2)),
                      ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at [VGG's `forward` function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/vgg.html):

```py
def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

You'll notice the `torch.flatten` call *before* `self.classifier` kicks in. This is why you get the input as a "flatten" 2D feature vector.

You might be able to "undo" the `torch.flatten` using [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) or [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.reshape), but you'll need to know the spatial dimensions of the input and how they affect the spatial shape of the feature map. That is, the feature map is of shape `batch`-by-512-7-7 only for inputs of shape `batch`-by-3-224-224. If you change the input size (since the net up to this point is fully convolutional) the feature map shape might change.